# TFS Pending Changes: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have TFS 2017 Express on my server machine and Visual studio Community 2017 RC as well. I keep getting this error message when I browse to "Pending Changes" option in Team Explorer in Visual Studio

> An item with the same key has already been added.

I dont have *any* pending changes on my PC and none of the PCs that are connected to the same server.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the time of your post I assume you have been able to overcome this issue. But for the others like me who run into the same problem here is the solution.

Delete the Team Foundation Service cache folder and restart Visual Studio i.e.

C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation[Version]\Cache