# Azure DevOps Build - Invoke-RestMethod - An item with the same key has already been added error

Tags: azure-devops

We have a powershell script as a step in our DevOps build that finds changeset details since the last good build.

```
$TfsUrl = 'https://' + $RestAPIAccount + '.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/' + $ProjectName
$BaseUrl =  "https://" + $RestAPIAccount + ".visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets"
$ChangeSetHistoryUrl = $TfsUrl + "/_apis/build/builds/$BuildId/changes?api-version=$RestAPIVersion"
$changeSetHistoryDef = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ChangeSetHistoryUrl -Headers $Headers -Method Get).Value
```

The last statement has starting failing with the following error:

```
"Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"An item with the same key has already been added.","typeName":"System.ArgumentException, mscorlib, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","typeKey":"ArgumentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}"
```

We have been running the same script without any issues for the last year or more.

Any ideas on what could be causing this or how to troubleshoot further.

Comment: There is a similar issue with the solution for TFS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47808861/7073340), not sure this helps for azuredevops

Comment: I tried the solution in that post (clearing cache) but it did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our build steps are working this morning, without any changes being made to our process.

Test cases I had used to troubleshoot this issue earlier in the week using particular build id's that were failing are now working also.

Something must have changed by Microsoft which has subsequently been fixed??

Answer (score 0):

That's because the build you requested has no changes since the last good build.

Based on my test, if you have **2** build definitions **A** and **B**, and they have set the same sources... Edit and modify some files/code then check in the changes.

1. Trigger build definition **A** and generate a `build#1`, this time
   it works by calling below REST API:

   ```
   _apis/build/builds/build#1/changes?api-version=$RestAPIVersion
   ```
2. Then trigger build definition **B** and generate `build#2`, even they used the same Source version, but this
   time the REST API does not work... and you will get the error message... Because `build#2`have no changes compare with `build#1`...

   `_apis/build/builds/build#2/changes?api-version=$RestAPIVersion`  (build#2/changes will not work here as no changes....)

[image]

Tested with below script: ([Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=vsts#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api))

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/builds/$env:Build_BuildId/changes"
Write-Host $url
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}

Write-Host "Pipeline:" $pipeline.value | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

Comment: I don't believe this was the issue as there was changes between the 2 builds.  I tried similar test cases to you.

Comment: @MartinaRaf However I cannot reproduce the issue if I check some changes before the next build... Only using the same source version to trigger the next build can reproduce this issue on my side..